# $\int_0^1 e^{g(s)-1}ds $ where $g(s) = \sum\limits_{i\geq 1} \frac{ s^i i^{i-1} e^{-i}}{i!}.$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evaluate the following integral
$$ I:= \int_0^1  e^{g(s)-1}ds $$
where
$$g(s) = \sum\limits_{i\geq 1} \frac{ s^i i^{i-1} e^{-i}}{i!}.$$
I am pretty much stuck completely... In particular, I am not used to working with sums that include the nasty $i^{i-1}$ term. I did [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5En+e%5E%28-n%29+n%5E%28n-1%29+%2F+n%21%2C++n%3D1+to+infinity+++) that the sum $g(s)$ indeed converges for $|s|\leq 1$, but I am not sure what it converges to.

From other considerations, I know that $I = \int_0^1 \frac{g(s)}{s} ds$. Now, modulo some arguments for the exchanging of sums and integrations, we then have
$$  I = \sum\limits_{i\geq 1} \int_0^1  \frac{s^{i-1} i^{i-1}e^{-i}}{i!}ds = \sum\limits_{i\geq 1} \left [ \frac{s^{i} i^{i-2}e^{-i}}{i!} \right]_0^1 = \sum\limits_{i\geq 1} \frac{s^{i} i^{i-2}e^{-i}}{i!}  .$$
But I still have no idea how so rewrite the right hand side. I did numerically approximate both expressions for the integral and the last sum, and they all roughly equal $\frac{1}{2}$, so I think that is what the answer should be. Any help will be appreciated.

**Note:** I have shown the recurrence $g(s)=s e^{g(s)-1}$, which is how I obtained the different integral forms. Perhaps repeated applications of this relation might be useful, but I am not so sure how. Especially because the relation $x=e^x$ is already a tricky one.

**Potential progress:** Let $w = g(s)-1 = se^{w} - 1$, so that $s=(w+1)e^{-w}$. Then $\frac{dw}{ds} =e^w + s \frac{dw}{ds} e^w = e^w +(w+1) \frac{dw}{ds} $ giving $\frac{dw}{ds} = -e^{w}/w$. Then the integral becomes something like
$$ - \int \frac{e^{2w}}{w} dw $$

Comment: Just a note: By Stirling's formula, $\frac{{i^{i - 1} e^{ - i} }}{{i!}} \sim \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\frac{1}{{i^{3/2} }}$, showing the convergence for $|s|\leq 1$.

Comment: Your function $g$ can be expressed in terms of the Lambert-$W$ function, see the convergent power series in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions Properties of this function may help you evaluating $I$.

Comment: @Gary Good point with Stirling's Approximation. I will have a look at Lambert W functions!

Comment: You may use a change of integration variables since $g( - es) $ is the inverse of $s \mapsto  - se^{ - s}$.

Comment: @Gary Hmm how would I use that to solve for $I$?

Comment: I am not sure if you can use it here but note that the exponential of a sum is the product of the exponential of the terms

Comment: In broad strokes, how does $g(s)$ arise?

Comment: @Aruralreader I cannot for the life of me remember :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $w = g(s) - 1$, then $s = (w + 1)\mathrm{e}^{ - w}$ and $\mathrm{d}s =  - w \mathrm{e}^{ - w}\mathrm{d}w $. Thus
$$
\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{g(s) - 1} \mathrm{d}s =  - \int_{ - 1}^0 \mathrm{e}^w w\mathrm{e}^{ - w} \mathrm{d}w =  - \int_{ - 1}^0 w\, \mathrm{d}w = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Ah right, I see I was almost there but made a stupid error in calculating $ds$. Thanks!

Comment: We are not far from Lambert's W function...